# Solve z in an expression involving complex conjugates.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Solve for z, and give your answer in the form a+bi.

$$\overline{z+2-2i} = {2z + 5 - 7i}$$

I know fully understand the concept of complex numbers and complex conjugates. I've found that the answer is

$$ z = -3+3i $$

I don't know any proper methods to find the answer though, since I found this answer largely by trial and error. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could write $z = x+iy$, identify real and imaginary parts and find $x$ and $y$...

Comment: Set $z=a+bi$...

Comment: Use the fact that $z=a+bi$ and equate the real and imaginary parts of both sides of the equation.

Comment: Ah, that simple. Silly old me. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given equation is equivalent to

$$\overline z=2z+3-9i\implies z=2\overline z+3+9i=2(2z+3-9i)+3+9i=4z+9-9i$$
so we solve for $z$ we find

$$z=-3+3i$$